# Python regexp to get url without http or www

Tags: python, regex

How can I get only site.com from search results using python to get insights about words in google seach ?

```
from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError
try:
  page = 1
  gs = GoogleSearch("#hashtag insights")
  gs.results_per_page = 100
  results = []
  while True:
    tmp = gs.get_results()
    if not tmp: # no more results were found
      break
    results.extend(tmp)
  # ... do something with all the results ...
except SearchError, e:
  print "Search failed: %s" % e

for res in results:
    print res.url
```

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Comment: @sshashank124 No , I am newbie in Python so I am figuring out how to implement the answers into the code I found but no luck till now

Comment: it works with `urlparse` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex for that, use `urlparse`

```
hostname = urlparse.urlparse("http://www.techcrunch.com/").hostname
```

http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html

Answer (score 0):

Try it with regex as follows:

```
import re
s = 'http://www.google.com'

>>> print re.search(r'^https?:\/\/www\.(.*)$', s).group(1)
google.com
```

If you have a more general site, you can do:

```
import re
s = 'http://username.blogspot.com'

>>> print re.search(r'^https?:\/\/[^.]*.(.*)$', s).group(1)
blogspot.com
```